# Storing Null in SQlite Database for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

i am trying to implement following Code...

```
String updateQuery ="INSERT INTO MAAccounts(userId, accountId, accountType, accountName, parentAccountId ) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 


        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, new String[]{
                stringToDB(account.userId),
                integerToDB(account.accountId).toString(),
                integerToDB(account.accountType.getValue()).toString(),
                stringToDB(account.accountName),
                integerToDB(account.parentAccountId).toString(),
                });
```

Now the initial value of parentAccoudId (Type int ) is null. It is actually converting null to to.String

When i try to run it gives error of Null pointer.

I want to store null value in database please tell me how can i do that.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
account.parentAccountId != null ? 
  integerToDB(account.parentAccountId).toString() : "null"
```

Comment: ok i did that but it now says that bind value at index 4 is null. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just detect if its null. If it is null then insert "null" into the database.